# UIImageView round border with margin

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm using this code to create rounder UIImageView:

```
-(void) makeImageViewRounded {
    self.layer.backgroundColor=[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];
    self.layer.cornerRadius= self.frame.size.height /2;
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.layer.borderWidth=1.5;
    self.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
}
```

this is the outcome (ignore the background if the jpg.. it starts from the rounded border):

[image]

I want create a margin between the image and the rounded border to this outcome (ignore the background if the jpg.. it starts from the rounded border):

[image]

How can i achieve that ?

Comment: add another layer mask for margin

Comment: @rptwsthi can you please provide some extra code ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured a way, make a UIView subclass called CircleView, in its implementation, add

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 20.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,
                                     [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor);
    CGRect rectangle = self.bounds;
    CGFloat lineWidth = self.superview.layer.borderWidth;
    rectangle = CGRectInset(rectangle, lineWidth, lineWidth);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}


     //Then add this circle view to your imageView
    CircleView *circle = [[CircleView alloc]initWithFrame:imageView.bounds];
    [imageView addSubview:circle];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using the [setContentsRect:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/contentsRect) method of the UIImageView's layer.